# Python Pandas: populate a column until a different value appears?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am working on an algo trading project using the pandas and numpy libraries and would like to achieve the following result:

Current output:

```
1
0
0
2
0
2
0
0
4
0
0
0
5
```

desired output:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
4
4
4
4
5
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `0` by `NA` then fill forward:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(0, pd.NA).ffill()
print(df)

# Output
    col1
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
6      2
7      2
8      4
9      4
10     4
11     4
12     5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `method` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```

```
print(df)

    col
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     4
9     4
10    4
11    4
12    5
```